# copy/paste vlookup,that looks up 2 criteria,where 1 of criteria is static and other dynamic

Tags: microsoft-excel

`=VLOOKUP(B1&A3,'cstmr data'!1:65536,8,FALSE)`           hi, I am unable to drag this formula to other cells in the same column. I need cell B1 to remain static and cell A3 would correspond to the given row.  please advise. thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to check out `absolute references`.

Placing a `$` before the letter or number in a cell reference stops Excel from changing the reference as you copy the formula. So you need to alter the formula to

```
=VLOOKUP($B$1&A3,'cstmr data'!1:65536,8,FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question.  Your formula format worked for 2 of the formulas, but the other 2 are not outputting data and just outputing the formula, not even with an error.  please advise